# How many molecules does the Mississippi River discharge every minute?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A liter of water contains about $3.35 \times 10^{25}$ molecules. The Mississippi River discharges about $1.7 \times 10^7$ liters of water every second.

I try to multiply $(3.35\times 1.7) (10^{25}\times10^7)$ and then I got $(5.695)$ and in the book said you have to add the exponent $(10^{25+7})=10^{32}$ then I got lost.${}$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't just post the question here. Post it with your work. That work does not have to be correct\complete.

Comment: I try to multiply (3.35x1.7) (10^25x10^7) and then I got (5.695) and in the book said you have to add the exponent (10^25+^7)=10^32 then I got lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $1$ liter contains $3.35 \cdot 10^{25}$ molecules, then the river discharges $$3.35\cdot 10^{25} \times 1.7 \cdot 10^7 = 3.35\cdot1.7\cdot10^{32}$$
molecules per second.

Since one minute is equivalent to $60$ seconds, the answer is
$$60\cdot3.35\cdot1.7\times10^{32} = 341.7\times10^{32} = 3.417\times10^{34}.$$

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> I try to multiply (3.35x1.7) (10^25x10^7) and then I got (5.695) and in the book said you have to add the exponent (10^25+^7)=10^32 then I got lost

I think this is your real question.  It's why we ask people to post their work along with the question they're working on.  You understand that the numbers need to be multiplied, but  you got lost with:
$$
    10^{25} \cdot 10^7 = 10^{25+7} = 10^{32}
$$
Think about what $10^{25}$ is: The product of $25$ $10$s written in a row.  Similarly for $10^7$.  So $10^{25} \cdot 10^7$ is the concatenation of $25$ $10$s and $7$ more $10$s.  That's $32$ $10$s altogether, or $10^{32}$.

In general, $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$.  This is a rule of exponents that is true even when the exponents are negative or fractional.